# How to display database RANDOM in android listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview

anyone know hot to display **random** data from database in mysql and display in listview?

i can display all data without random, but i want to displayed it random, anyone can help?

my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length() ; i++) {

                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("KindOf").equals(textKind.getText().toString()) && obj.getString("Type").equals("Strength")) {
                                          exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("Type"));
                                          exercise.setJenis(obj.getString("KindOf"));
                                          exercise.setNama(obj.getString("Name"));


                                          exerciseList.add(exercise);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
```

Comment: if `exerciseList ` is ArrayList then use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shuffle an ArrayList, you can just use the Collections `shuffle` method.

```
Collections.shuffle(exerciseList);
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM excercises
ORDER BY RAND();
```

If you want it at DB level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw, if thats code for random the result of exercise, but actually i want to random fetch data from database and display in `exerciseList`

Comment: I am not sure if we can achieve that at DB level. Check the edited answer, from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a random number with

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(exerciseList.size());
```

Then use the random number as an index to get an item from your exerciseList and add it to a new array if it doesnt exist there yet.

Answer (score 0):

To random ArrayList, you can just use the Collections shuffle method.

```
Collections.shuffle(exerciseList);
```

Or you can use random function in web service method when you access data from database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw, if thats code for random the result of exercise, but actually i want to random fetch data from database and display in `exerciseList`